# Bubble Sort Program

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I am creating a bubble sort program which sorts random integers in an array. The array is supposed to be able to hold up to a million sorted integers. When I get to a high number (for example, 250,000) the program will sit there and never output anything. Code is below:

```
using System;

namespace SortingProject
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //create an array to hold integers
            int[] list = new int[50000];

            //call random function to populate integer values
            Random rand = new Random();

            //add integers to array
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++) {

                list[i] = rand.Next(1,50000);
            }

            //call bubble sort method and input the array
            BubbleSorting(list);

        }

        //bubble sort method and logic

        public static void BubbleSorting(int[] array)
        {

            //initialize time start 
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime end;

            end = DateTime.Now;


            //initialize element integer
            int element = 0;

            for (int bubble = 0; bubble < array.Length; bubble++)
            {
                //create for loop to perform bubble sort
                for (int sort = 0; sort < array.Length - 1; sort++)
                {

                    if (array[sort] > array[sort + 1])
                    {
                        element = array[sort + 1];

                        array[sort + 1] = array[sort];

                        array[sort] = element;
                    }
                }

            }

            //loop and print array contents
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)

                Console.Write(array[i] + " ");


            //calculate time it takes to sort array
            end = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan ts = end.Subtract(start);
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("Duration = {0} ms", ts.TotalMilliseconds);
        }
    }
    }
```

I usually wait for awhile while the program is running but it seems to be freezing with larger arrays. Any help on why would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that you simply understimate that the time to complete scales **literally** exponentially O(n^2)?

Comment: Note that bubble sort is O(n^2) in running time complexity. Meaning, as you increase the input size (list length) the computation takes more and more time to compute the answer. You should see a super-linear increase in running time with larger inputs. Have you tried some other inputs to see if you can find a length where it stops working?

Comment: for every element in the array, do something with every element in the array, think about how that scales. type in to your calculator, number of elements then hit the x2 button, see what it does

Comment: Is there code I could use to show that the program is still running? It just sits there so it's hard to know if it's still running.

Comment: You could place break points to understand where your code is spending all it's time OR since this is a console app, you could add a line like if (bubble % 1000 == 0)  Console.WriteLine($"Still running: {bubble}");  to your bubble for loop.  It's not dead, it just needs more time to process.

Comment: BubbleSort is very useful as an academic exercise to show how sorting works, and how it can be implemented in a given programming language. The quadratic time complexity, as you have discovered, is the precise reason this algorithm is not used in production code.

Comment: As others have noted, the time it takes is proportional to the square of the input size; a bubble sort that sorts ten elements will do about 100 comparisons; a bubble sort that sorts a million elements will do about a million million comparisons.  If your machine can do a billion comparisons a second, it will take about a thousand seconds. So your observation is to be expected.

Comment: For your future reference, I suggest you use the `Stopwatch` class rather than `DateTime.Now` for timing code.  `DateTime.Now` is only precise to a few milliseconds, which is fine for your situation where you are running programs that take seconds, minutes or hours. But get in the habit of using `Stopwatch` for your timing needs, as it is far more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Tested the code and it runs fine (tested 250000 values). As pointed in the comments The Bubble Sort algorithm is not the most optimized one. Its complexity is given by:

```
for (int bubble = 0; bubble < array.Length; bubble++) 
{
    //create for loop to perform bubble sort
    for (int sort = 0; sort < array.Length - 1; sort++)
    {
       \\do logic
    }
 }
```

The outer for loop will do N loops. The inner for loop will do N loops.
The big O notation will have a complexity of N*N , therefore we have O(N^2).

With 250000 values there will be 62,500,000,000 iterations.

Keeping that in mind the complexity (time taken if you will) is directly proportional to the number of values N, the more values you need to sort the longer the Bubble sort will take to complete.